# How to create a Location arrow Marker with Sensor bearing in Android Google Maps v2?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I have managed to create an arrow `ImageView` and get the azimuth from the sensors, after that I rotate the `ImageView` using `setRotation()` method of the `View` class. How I can do this for a marker using Android Google Maps v2 Markers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/) project from Google.

It contains

- [BubbleIconFactory](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/ui/BubbleIconFactory.java) : Responsible for generating markers
- [RotationLayout](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/ui/RotationLayout.java) : Responsible for rotating the contents of the layout (the marker) by multiples of 90 degrees

This should give you the building blocks you need to display your arrow/marker and give it a certain rotation. You'll probably need to customize the rotationlayout a bit.

Comment: In the end this is a layout, I need to do all this on a Marker object.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to rotate your custom marker icon. It can only be done through the bitmap. The bitmap can be rotated using this rotationLayout. If can be set on the marker using setIcon.

Answer (score 1):

you can use: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#rotate_a_marker

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker = addMapMarker(camera,PrefManager.getCurrentUsername(getActivity()),
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.overlay_gps_location_scanner_icon));
marker.setRotation(0);
```