# Android Google Maps - Orientation arrow for the position marker

Tags: android, geolocation, position, bearing

I'm using Google Map developer, but my position marker doesn't show the orientation or bearing of the calculated position.

Google Map library: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'`

[image]
[image]

Comment: look two photo,you will understand my question better.

Comment: That's google map navigation app.it will not same in your application if your enable mylocation in your app though.

Comment: i already set location enable true,and i try to set every ui setting,but it not works.the location still not arrow...and i have looked other apps have arrows.@AnoopM

Comment: In short you will not get the arrow by using google map until your customizing such features.it's not the default.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338900/how-to-create-a-location-arrow-marker-with-sensor-bearing-in-android-google-maps The problem here was clearly the inability to phrase the question properly, this question and answers should help you. Let me retag this for you

Comment: what do you means?is there any way to get arrow?i try to add Sensor listener,but just the map rotate,how to show the arrow?@AnoopM

Comment: The arrow is not *added* to the position marker. It's a whole bitmap, which includes the arrow, and is *rotated* according to what the `Location.getBearing()` method returns. Read the question I linked to

Comment: do you means i need add a market like the arrow,and add the sensor listener to change the market rotation,i use location.getBearing() on onMyLocationChange return 0. @JuanCortés